# lazy_high_charts and foundation conflict loading javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, lazy-high-charts

I'm using `lazy_high_charts` and `foundation 4`.

In my view I have `<%= high_chart("my_id", @chart) %>`, which generates the following:

```
<section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var onload = window.onload;                      # I think
      window.onload = function(){                      # the issue
        if (typeof onload == "function") onload();     # is here
          var options = { "title": { "text": "Combination chart" },"legend": { "layout": "vertical","style": {  } },"xAxis": {  },"yAxis": { "title": { "text": null },"labels": {  } },"tooltip": { "enabled": true },"credits": { "enabled": false },"plotOptions": { "areaspline": {  } },"chart": { "defaultSeriesType": "line","renderTo": "my_id" },"subtitle": {  },"series": [{ "type": "spline","name": "Average","data": [ 3,2.67,3,6.33,3.33 ] }] };

    window.chart_my_id = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

      };
    })()
  </script>
<div id="my_id"></div>
</section>
```

However, it is not displaying because of the following lines generated by `foundation 4` in my `application.js`

```
$(document).foundation();
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

If I delete those lines the chart loads.

How can I use `foundation` and `lazy_high_charts` together?

Comment: Same thing happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem updating the `zurb-foundation` and `lazy_high_charts` gems:

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'lazy_high_charts'
```

Then:

```
bundle install
bundle update lazy_high_charts
rails g foundation:install
```

I have also included the following lines in the `application.html.erb`:

```
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  ...
```

After that, the `<%= high_chart("my_id", @chart) %>` code is generating the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
(function() {
  var f = function(){
  document.removeEventListener('page:load', f, true);
...
```

I hope it helps people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
(function() {
var onload = window.onload;                      # I think
window.onload = function(){                      # the issue
```

write

```
$(function(){
```

The resulting script tag will look:

```
<section>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          var options = { "title": { "text": "Combination chart" },"legend": { "layout": "vertical","style": {  } },"xAxis": {  },"yAxis": { "title": { "text": null },"labels": {  } },"tooltip": { "enabled": true },"credits": { "enabled": false },"plotOptions": { "areaspline": {  } },"chart": { "defaultSeriesType": "line","renderTo": "my_id" },"subtitle": {  },"series": [{ "type": "spline","name": "Average","data": [ 3,2.67,3,6.33,3.33 ] }] };

    window.chart_my_id = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
  </script>
<div id="my_id"></div>
</section>
```

Make sure you have put jquery script before it.

Comment: This solution works, but isn't there a better option? I don't know JavaScript very well, something like disabling foundation here, or make highcahrts js's priority first. Sorry if dumb question.

Comment: Any code you write inside `$(function(){ ... });` will be executed on page load just after previous ones in previous `$(function(){...});` commands. So if the line `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` appears after `$(function() { ... window.chart_my_id = new Highcharts.Chart(options);});` , Highchart's priority will be first. Also the first line `$(document).foundation();` in your question is redundant. `
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` does the whole work.

Comment: The `<%= high_chart("my_id", @chart) %>` generates the javascript code. So, it is not possible to edit the javascript generated by the `lazy_high_charts`.